# Styling the default html select without external background image for arrow

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, reactjs

I have a html select box which has default native look and feel.I want to customize it without using any external background image e.g.`background: url('dropdown_arrow.png') no-repeat;`
I know that there is another way to do it using `<span class="caret"></span>` but can't figure it out.

```
<select className="form-control" value={this.state.selectValue}
        onChange={this.handleChange} >
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: try `Selectpicker` which uses bootstrap, here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/zkcgfcyL/)

Comment: You are also using some external css files and js e.g bootstrap-select.cs and bootstrap-select.js

Comment: you dont want to use bootstrap-select ? do u need only bootstrap?

Comment: Yes.I don't want to use any external library other than bootstrap.

Comment: updated fiddle with only css